# Algebra vs. Geometry: understanding a quote by Michael Atiyah

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, soft-question, math-history

> *Algebra is the offer made by the devil to the mathematician. The devil says: "I will give you this powerful machine, it will answer any question you like. All you need to do is give me your soul: give up geometry and you will have this marvelous machine.* -- Michael Atiyah

This captivating remark confuses me -- what is the fundamental difference between algebra and geometry? I thought these labels more represented historical trends in mathematical inquiry rather than real technical distinctions. See [Difference between algebra and geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2384948/793719)

Atiyah seems to be suggesting a distinction between the reasoning/axioms associated with geometry and those associated with algebra. Is there a difference? If so, what is it?

Comment: Atiyah saw mathematicians forming two tribes: geometers and algebraists. He saw himself as a member of the superior tribe: a geometer.

Comment: I recommend to read the intreduction of David Hilbert's book "Geometry and the Imagination" or its German original "Anschauliche Geometrie" from 1932.

Comment: There’s a story, likely apocryphal, that Chevalley and Zariski were discussing curves, and it became clear that there was some misunderstanding. “What do you mean by a curve, anyhow?” says Z to C, and C writes on the board $f(x,y)=0$. Then Z takes the chalk and makes a looping figure on the board.

Comment: +1. @Lubin: I don't understand the point of your story? and is that related to OP question?

Comment: Then point, @C.F.G , is that there are (were) two very different approaches to what even such a simple concept as “curve” is about. For the algebraist, it’s an equation, while to the geometer, it’s a picture. And I think that the debate between C and Z goes to the heart of this question and of the quote from Atiyah.

Comment: Thanks. This part of quote refers to Soul Theorem that has been proved by Perelman: _All you need to do is give me your soul: give up geometry_

Comment: I found the quote [here](https://people.math.umass.edu/~hacking/461F19/handouts/atiyah.pdf). I cannot see how this is related to Soul theorem. @C.F.G

Comment: @ArcticChar: I find it. It was mathoverflow comments: [See here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7155/famous-mathematical-quotes/7203#comment12929_7203)

Comment: Thanks @C.F.G . but I still cannot see how it is related/inspired to Soul theorem. The proof of the Soul theorem is highly (Riemannian) geometric.

Comment: Solomon Lefschetz
– If it’s just turning the crank it’s _algebra_, but if it’s got an idea in it, it’s
_topology_.

Comment: When i stumbled upon this quote i caught myself smiling. It's just my personal experience, but my deep interest in topology was purely motivated by geometry, i liked the visual character of topology. However, the deeper i tried (still do) to dive into topology, the more i got confronted by algebra. Since algebra seemed to be the answer to so many of my initial questions, i somehow started getting more interested in the algebra itself and left the geometry behind. But this is just a personal anekdote, but i found this quote to fit so well to my personal experience with topology.